# how do we order by and select top 20% records in an order in sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TOP (20)percent count(*)  FROM (SELECT [col1],col2
FROM [report].[detailsprovider] 
WHERE [col3] = 2  group by [col1] as t  order by t.col2
```

I am trying to do this, but getting stuck in order by and group by.

I want the distinct count of col1 with top 20% ordered(based on col2) count/list of rows

Comment: Can you show example data and desired results?

Comment: like col1 should be distinct...

Comment: provide column names and some example so that it can be understood what you want

Comment: select top (20)percent servicer,Score,Bandval  into #tmp from [report].[serviceprovider] 
WHERE [Bandval  ] = 2 order by Score

select count([Bandval]) , [servicer] from #tmp group by [servicer]        I want this to happen in a single query

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), col1
FROM (SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT col1 FROM myTable WHERE col3=2
ORDER BY col2) a
GROUP BY col1
```

**NOTE:** This is for TSQL.  I'm not sure what other SQL flavors contain `PERCENT`

Comment: @user2637506 Glad to be of help.  Next time, please include more information in your questions (is it MySQL, TSQL, PostGre,....?)  Other helpful information can include version numbers, error messages, what you have tried, and of course your code.  This helps us answer your questions as accurately as possible.